# run multiple commands in windows cmd using Process class in java

Tags: java, miktex, cm

Im using a java application for creating a .pdf file. It writes the .tex file so Miktex can create a pdf.

```
writePDF(s);
    String command = "cmd /c start xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode " + s + ".tex && del " + s + ".tex";  
    Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
    p = r.exec(command);
    p.waitFor();
```

but the only thing that happens is textput.log being created with the following contents:

```
entering extended mode
**aa.tex

! Emergency stop.
<*> aa.tex

*** (job aborted, file error in nonstop mode)
```

The strange thing is that when i run that command directly on windows cmd it works fine. If i also make the "command" variable like this and run it withing java app it works fine aswell.

```
String command = "cmd /c start xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode " + s + ".tex"
```

I'm using java 8 and Miktex 2.9.7
Hope you can help

Comment: Hi @Varejator, I added an example of how to achieve this.

Comment: doesn't work. it gives a message back: cannot run program ... create processerror=2 system cannot find specific file. but it wrote the .tex file

Comment: cannot run program cmd /c start (and so on) create ProcessorError=2 System cannot find specified file.

Comment: And from my example, if you remove the second command "del " + s + ".tex" and leave the array with 1 element, does it work without the message?

Comment: doesnt work, only if use String not String[]

Comment: Sorry, I dont have a Windows machine .. and if you leave only one command and then remove the "cmd /c " from the start ,does it work? For me it works in Mac.

Comment: Don't worry, no it doesn't.. guess i will check the website @davidbuzatto had mencioned

Comment: guess i've found out something, the 2 processes run parallel. one deletes the file so the other cant find it

Comment: @Brother i've found some kind of solution, i write a .bat file with all the commands i want and execute it within a java process.

Comment: That is nice @Varejator! .. 
Another thing you could do is have an array of commands and loop, executing in order.

Comment: @Brother it keeps running parallel. It works well if i only use native shell commands like "dir","ping" but when i try using an app like xelatex it runs in parallel. What i think its happening is that when it calls xelatex it creates another process so the current one keeps looping though commands anyway.

Comment: Hey .. so what happens if you remove the "cmd /c start" from the beginning, leaving only the XeLaTeX command? does it work? I think this cmd /c start it is causing the parallel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in order to execute multiple commands in Java in sequence (not parallel), you can try to run like this:

```
    String[] commands = new String[] {"xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode " + s + ".tex"
                                   , "del " + s + ".tex"};  
    Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process p;
    for (String command: commands) {
      p = r.exec(command);
      p.waitFor();
    }
```

Comment: hey @varejator, according to other places, you can run "xelatex" without specifying "cmd /c start " that causes to run in another terminal. that it is probably why it runs in parallel

Comment: it works that way, the only problem now is that first process doesnt finish but at least the 2nd one doesnt start

Answer (score 0):

Besides how to call multiple commands, as @Brother already said, you **MUST** take a look here: https://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html

This article explains how to use `Runtime.exec()` properly, i.e., you must consume all process output streams (standard and error) completely.

Comment: Gonna see that but shouldn't it give the same problem if i use only one command?

Comment: @Varejator for one or n commands you must consume all output streams. Read the article!